# binding html radio buttons

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, data-binding, controls

I have a list of input type radio buttons in formview (edit mode) and i want to bind data from datasource that is assigned to formview.
Can i bind html radio buttons using sql datasource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used selected = '<% Bind("xyz") %>'

Answer (score 0):

All controls can be bound with a SQL datasource, as they all inherit from [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.aspx) where it defined.

Here are a [couple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7k30eyz%28VS.71%29.aspx) of [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163959.aspx) describing how to bind `RadioButtonList`.

Comment: can you direct me to an example of how to bind input type radio group?

Comment: I'm not using radio button list but I'm using <input type="radio" />

Comment: You can't databind a control that is not server side (i.e. with a `runat="server"` attribute). You should be using serverside controls, such as RadioButtonList for this.

Answer (score 0):

i was looking to bind input radio type you can do that using checked='<# Bind("Selected") >' and using runat="server" Note: my rdb list is in data controls